# Retrive form values & combine them & send them to another page

Tags: php

I want combine the textbox's and the radio button's value and  pass it to the **file.php** when the page is redirected. when the file name with extension is send to **file.php** it will create the file in a folder and let a user download it (just for description).
I have a bad feeling that my code has some serious problems. I don't know how to retrieve the form values and then combine them. obviously this code gives error. Need help to understand the error and fix it.

```
<?php
<form name="np_form"  method="post" >   
File Name:
<input type="text" name="n" class="bar"/> <br/>
Choose Extension:  
<input type="radio" name="file"  value=".doc">.doc <br/>
<input type="radio" name="file"  value=".ppt">.ppt <br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create & Download" onclick="return  validation()" formaction="file.php?$filename=form['np_form']['n'].form['np_form']['file']" /> 
</form>
?>
```

**the error I got:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'np_form' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sss\inside_box_EFN.php on line 8

---thanks. Hope you people understood my problem.

Comment: You have got syntax error on `line 8` in `inside_box_EFN.php`. `,` or `;` is expected but you have got string there.

Answer (score 0):

you did not echo the html page, friend and that is why you're having an error. Also you can use the ACTION attribute in the form tag rather than use your submit's attributes.

```
<?php

echo   '<form name="np_form"  method="POST" Action="file.php" >   
File Name:
<input type="text" name="n" class="bar"/> <br/>
Choose Extension:  
<input type="radio" name="file"  value=".doc">.doc <br/>
<input type="radio" name="file"  value=".ppt">.ppt <br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create & Download" onclick="return    
 validation()" /> 
</form>';

?>
```